# Insert new records in second table based on colums in first table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am New to oracle.I have tow tables name "st" and "mt"."skey" is the common column for two tables.I wanted to insert data in "mt" for all "skey" values of "st" except when column name "tes" in "st" not equal to 'NOO'.

```
 INSERT INTO SDATA.MT(RECNO,Skey,Date)
 VALUES ((SELECT MAX(RECNO) FROM SDATA.ST)+1,'hari..',sysdate)
 where skey in (select skey from SDATA.ST where tes <> 'NOO')
```

Getting Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the logic behind your query is corrrect, you only need the correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO SDATA.MT(
                     RECNO,
                     Skey,
                     Date
                    )
    SELECT MAX(RECNO) + 1,
           'hari..',
           SYSDATE
      FROM C_WOMEN_PRD.MOSTATUS
     WHERE skey IN (SELECT skey
                      FROM SDATA.ST
                     WHERE tes <> 'NOO')
```

You need the VALUES keyword to insert fixed values:

```
INSERT INTO SDATA.MT(
                         RECNO,
                         Skey,
                         Date
                        )
VALUES (1,
        'something',
        sysdate
       );
```

Depending on the data in your tables, maybe you need

```
WHERE skey NOT IN (SELECT skey
                          FROM SDATA.ST
                         WHERE tes = 'NOO')
```

instead of your condition; but this only can be said knowing how your data are.

Comment: still  error SQL Error: unique constraint (%s.%s) violated

Comment: Thank You very much.."Not In" Worked.Very helpful.